# Autofocus first form element inside active div in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with several divs (10+) and I display only 1 at a time whereas the rest are set to `display: hidden`.When I click on the `Next` button, the current div gets hidden and the next one gets visible. There is a `Previous` button too.
Is there a way to focus the first form element of the currently visible div using JavaScript?
HTML Structure is as follows:

```
<form id = "myForm">
<div id="div1">
<!-------Div can hav 2 cols---->
    <div class = "row">
        <div class= "col">
            <input autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class = "col">
            <select></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2" style = "display: none;">
<!-------Or Div can have 1 col---->
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col">
             <!-------First element can be input---->
            <input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div3" style = "display: none;">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col">
             <!-------Or First element can be select---->
             <select> </select>
             <input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-------More Divs---->
</form>
```

The autofocus works on the first element but then I need to focus on the first elements of the rest of the divs inside the form using JavaScript.

Comment: In your next/previous code, you must show and hide divs, correct? Use `element.focus()` to focus on the given element.

Comment: Yes @Kobe but I'm struggling to find out the first form element inside each div. There are `row` `col` `h1` inside the divs too that occur before an `input` or `select` element.

Comment: can you please share you prev/next code?

Comment: Also, to solve that issue, use [queryselectorall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: @Kobe its exactly like you said, I'm changing the `display` from `none` to `flex` & I even have the ID of currently active `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'd have to use css :visible modifier and call this code everytime the change happens

Using jquery:

```
function focusOnVisible(){
    $("#myForm input:visible, #myForm input:visible").first().focus()
}
```

And then call this on pageload and after next button is clicked

```
$('document').ready(focusOnVisible);
$('.next').click(focusOnVisible);
```

Comment: The only problem is that a `select` can occur before `input`. Please check I have edited the question.

Comment: Then add select to the selector

Answer (score 1):

If you share your next and prev button click function then easy to understand your structure and able to give solution very simple way.

I have also prepare below thing for solution.

```
 $("#myForm > div:visible .col").first().find('input').focus();
```

you need to check every time when click on next and prev button.
So you need to add this code in next and prev function.

Edit : Please give one common class in form control(input, select, etc) and then use it in find element (replace class instead of input ).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form">
<input type="text"  />
<input type="text" />
<div>

</div>
</form>
<script>
var f = document.getElementById("form");
f[1].focus();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: f[0].focus() => focus the first element